# mysql - Sort by field in multiple select

Tags: mysql

1) I have query to retrieve id of files, like so:

```
SELECT virtuemart_media_id
FROM __virtuemart_product_medias
WHERE virtuemart_product_id = "1"
ORDER by ordering ASC
```

This gives me some ides, like 23, 7, 8, 24 and thats fine.

Then I need to use above values in another WHERE statement to select those files. Therefore I have something like this:

```
SELECT file_url, virtuemart_media_id
FROM __virtuemart_medias 
WHERE virtuemart_media_id IN (
    SELECT virtuemart_media_id
    FROM __virtuemart_product_medias
    WHERE virtuemart_product_id = "1"
    ORDER by ordering ASC
)
```

This also works except I got results of files which have order: 7, 8, 23, 24 - so not in order 23, 7, 8, 24.

Where is the problem? Seems like the ordering of inner SELECT is not preserved.

Comment: Well, haven't you answered your own question? Add another `ORDER BY`. But, no offense, this is a bit of an ugly way to write the query. You might be interested in this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

this will replace both of your queries.

```
SELECT __virtuemart_medias.file_url, __virtuemart_medias.virtuemart_media_id 
FROM __virtuemart_medias INNER JOIN __virtuemart_product_medias ON 
__virtuemart_medias.virtuemart_media_id=__virtuemart_product_medias.virtuemart_media_id WHERE 
__virtuemart_product_medias.virtuemart_product_id = '1' ORDER BY 
__virtuemart_product_medias.ordering ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.file_url, a.virtuemart_media_id
FROM __virtuemart_medias a
INNER JOIN __virtuemart_product_medias b  ON a.virtuemart_media_id  = b.virtuemart_media_id
ORDER BY b.ordering ASC;
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

There is no order in an IN clause. It is just a set of values. x in (1,2,3) is the same as x in (3,2,1) for (1,2,3) is the same set as (3,2,1). Join the tables to get access to your ordering column:

```
SELECT vm.file_url, vm.virtuemart_media_id
FROM __virtuemart_medias vm
INNER JOIN __virtuemart_product_medias vpm
  ON vm.virtuemart_media_id  = vpm.virtuemart_media_id
WHERE vpm.virtuemart_product_id = 1
ORDER BY vpm.ordering ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The subquery for `in` might produce multiple results.  In that case, you have to define which one you want for the ordering.

When replacing an `in` followed by a subquery with a `join`, you need to be sure that you don't accidentally multiply the number of records.  This requires using aggregation or `distinct` to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT m.file_url, m.virtuemart_media_id
FROM __virtuemart_medias  join
     (select virtuemart_media_id, min(ordering) as ordering
      from __virtuemart_product_medias
      where WHERE virtuemart_product_id = 1
      group by virtuemart_media_id
     ) mi
     on m.virtuemart_media_id = mi.virtuemart_media_id
ORDER by mi.ordering ASC;
```